# simple implementation of .gif loader not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a website that loads many images for certain pages, and need to implement a loading gif that appears within a div (#carousel) while the images are loading. The following website has a REALLY simple implementation that I followed but for some reason the loading gif does not display.

http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/

Here's my the link to my website where the gif should be loading:
http://www.lourdesgabrielainteriors.com/Projects.html

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On projects.html, line 286:

```
document.getElementById("carousel").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Aventura").innerHTML;
```

That removes the loader div since it is inside of `#carousel`.  You should place the loader div as a child of `<body>`.

Comment: so what's the thought process here that I'm doing wrong? where do I place the gif so that it does not get removed but I'm also still replacing the carousel's inner div

Comment: You can put the loader basically anywhere *except* in the carousel.  I would put it as the last child of `<body>`.

Comment: I did exactly that but strangely the loader is still not showing up

Comment: Yeah, that's really weird.  I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Max - Ok, here's my theory. I'm guessing it's something like chrome doesn't apply `::after` styles until the page has loaded. So, my brilliant idea failed. :)  Go back to doing it with a loader div, but include it as a child of `<body>`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: your solution now sort of works, however the loader trumps then entire page, instead of just the carousel. my question remains as to how I can insert the loader into the carousel div

Comment: Try inserting it as a sibling following carousel. Modify the position so that it is the same size as carousel. That may be easiest by putting them both in a relatively positioned container and setting `position: absolute` on the loader.

Comment: I figured it out, because the carousel's original opacity is set to 0, the gif never appears